# Apache Cordova: build .ipa file on Windows 8

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, ipa, phonegap

I have developed a cordova project on Windows 8. I have developed and build an apk file for Android devices and now I want to build the .ipa file for iPhone devices. My question is, 'Is there any way to create an .ipa file from the Cordova project on Windows OS?'. I don't have enough amount to buy a Macbook, and because of some reason I cannot install Mac OS with virtual machine like vmware. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an ipa on Windows, but there are alternatives to purchasing a mac. One popular service is MacInCloud. You could do a manual build, but there are also [instructions](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build_ios_cloud/) for running a remote build through Visual Studio.

Another option could be [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) which requires much less setup.

Comment: we can build .ipa file using windows by using a mac vm  and any way we need to purchase developer account for that

Comment: Thought it'd be nice to let people know: Phonegap build is not being maintained by Adobe anymore. Don't start new projects with it.

Answer (score 0):

macincloud is one of the options you have, since adobe build will not longer work in the future. There you have access to different subscription models, pay as you go, weekly etc.. and then you can build and submit your apps. Of course you need to pay the apple developer license.